MAUI CollectionView: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap
I am developing an Android Launcher application that needs to enumerate and display installed applications (I am using MAUI because I am more familiar with XAML layouts, and I am using the MVVM Community Toolkit). I have published a minimal repro on GitHub here - https://github.com/PaloMraz/MauiLauncherApp. This is a simple, one-page app:
The „Refresh Apps!“ button retrieves a list of installed applications using Adroid APIs encapsulated in the LauncherService class. It then populates an observable collection-typed property AppsForListView when the „Use Collection View (instead of ListView)?“ checkbox is not checked, or AppsForCollectionView otherwise.
The problem I am facing is that when the CollectionView is used, pressing the „Refresh Apps!“ second time, it generates „Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@91dbd84'“ and the app crashes. This also happens when pressing „Refresh Apps!“ once and the trying to scroll through the displayed app list.
The Debug output with the exception stack trace is here.
This problem does not occur when using the ListView control.
I have tested on Android emulator and also on two physical devices (Samsung Galaxy A70, Zebra TC78).
As I am not proficient with Android development, can you please provide me with some tips / workarounds?

Here is a related issue on GitHub, Carousel issue - Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap.

There is a bug caching Images on MAUI Collections
Solved by @mohachouch
Intermittent crash when navigating to a page containing images #9011

MauiProgram.cs (Tested)
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        ...
#if ANDROID
        ImageHandler.Mapper.PrependToMapping(nameof(Microsoft.Maui.IImage.Source), (handler, view) => PrependToMappingImageSource(handler, view));
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }

#if ANDROID
    public static void PrependToMappingImageSource(IImageHandler handler, Microsoft.Maui.IImage image)
    {
        handler.PlatformView?.Clear();
    }
#endif
}


Improved version by @Palo Mraz
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        ...
#if ANDROID     
        ImageHandler.Mapper.PrependToMapping(nameof(Microsoft.Maui.IImage.Source), (handler, view) => handler.PlatformView?.Clear());
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}


Failed attemps to get rid of the bug:
 internal static List<AppInfoRecord> Cache_AppInfoRecordList = new List<AppInfoRecord>();
 internal static List<AppInfoRecord_MemoryStream> Cache_AppInfoRecord_MemoryStreamList = new List<AppInfoRecord_MemoryStream>();
 internal static List<AppInfoRecord_Image> Cache_AppInfoRecord_Image_List = new List<AppInfoRecord_Image>();
 internal static List<AppInfoRecord_Bitmap> Cache_AppInfoRecord_Bitmap_List = new List<AppInfoRecord_Bitmap>();
 internal static List<AppInfoRecord_Drawable> Cache_AppInfoRecord_Drawable_List = new List<AppInfoRecord_Drawable>();

public partial class LauncherService
{
    ...
    public partial IEnumerable<AppInfoRecord> GetInstalledApps()
    {
        ...
        foreach (UserHandle userHandle in userManager.UserProfiles!)
        {
            ...
            foreach (var resolveActivityInfo in launcherApps.GetActivityList(null, userHandle)!)
            {
                var TryGetFrom_Cache_AppInfoRecord_Image_List = Cache.Cache_AppInfoRecord_Image_List.Where(x => x.PackageName == packageName).FirstOrDefault();
              
                if (TryGetFrom_Cache_AppInfoRecord_Image_List is null)
                {
                    var newAppInfoRecord_Image = new AppInfoRecord_Image(packageName, label, DrawableToImage(icon));

                    ImageSource imageSource = newAppInfoRecord_Image.Image.Source;
                    //ImageSource imageSource = DrawableToImageSource(icon);
                    //Bitmap bitmap = DrawableToBitmap(icon);
                    var new_AppInfoRecord = new AppInfoRecord(packageName, label, imageSource);
     
                    Cache.Cache_AppInfoRecord_Image_List.Add(newAppInfoRecord_Image);
                    yield return new_AppInfoRecord;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return new AppInfoRecord(packageName, label, TryGetFrom_Cache_AppInfoRecord_Image_List.Image.Source);
                    //yield return new AppInfoRecord(packageName, label, DrawableToImageSource(TryGetFrom_Cache_AppInfoRecord_Bitmap_List.icon_Drawable));
                    //yield return new AppInfoRecord(packageName, label, ImageSource.FromStream(() => TryGetFrom_Cache_AppInfoRecordList.MemoryStream_Icon), icon);
                    //yield return TryGetFrom_Cache_AppInfoRecordList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank, worked like a charm. Improved version, just one #if: #if ANDROID     ImageHandler.Mapper.PrependToMapping(nameof(Microsoft.Maui.IImage.Source), (handler, view) => handler.PlatformView?.Clear()); #endif

@Palo Mraz, Glad it works, I've spent 5 hours then I googled if there is a bug, next time I will start googling first. During that time I did many improvement for caching, you make think about it, I will include many of them in my answer. Good luck!

When I use the code below, I have a problem that the Image in CarouselView is not displayed, how can I fix this by leaving the Canvas error solution method: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap maui
public static class MauiProgram
{
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    ...
 #if ANDROID
    
 
ImageHandler.Mapper.PrependToMapping(nameof(Microsoft.Maui.IImage.Source), 
(handler, view) => PrependToMappingImageSource(handler, view));
#endif

    return builder.Build();
}

#if ANDROID
public static void PrependToMappingImageSource(IImageHandler handler, 
Microsoft.Maui.IImage image)
{
    handler.PlatformView?.Clear();
}
#endif
}

Here is the code of my CarouselView
using PDconfigurator.Helpers;
namespace PDconfigurator.View.Controls;

public partial class ImageModalPage : ContentPage
{
public ImageModalPage(List<ImageSource> imageSources, int initialIndex)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    carouselView.ItemsSource = imageSources;
    carouselView.KeepCarouselPosition(initialIndex);
    if (imageSources.Count == 1)
    {
        carouselView.IsSwipeEnabled = false;
    }
}


private async void OnSwipe(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
    await CloseModal();
}

private async Task CloseModal()
{
    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
}


I also encountered the similar issue that images on CollectionView aren't displayed when adding that android specific codes in MauiProgram.cs.
Instead of adding the android specific codes in MauiProgram.cs., the following solution that setting the WidthRequest and HeightRequest of the images worked for me.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9712#issuecomment-1312596405
